# Laravel cannot get response to parse foreign characters correctly

Tags: json, laravel, utf-8

After searching for a suitable answer, I find that the solutions people offer do not work so I am posting here in the hope of some help.

I have a database of users that will list by first letter of name in a directory. However there is one user that breaks the results because their name begins with a letter with a foreign character, namely Á.

I get the user results with:

```
$users = $this->users->getAll($params);
```

And then return the response using collection which json encodes it:

```
return response()->collection($users);
```

But I get the following error if the above user is returned in results:

> The Response content must be a string or object implementing
>   __toString(), 'boolean' given.

I've tried using the `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` option, like many people suggest in solutions, like this:

```
return response()->json($users, 200, ['Content-type'=> 'application/json; charset=utf-8'], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

but it turns out the response isn't coming back as UTF-8 after attempting to log it. However, as far as I can tell, the database is UTF-8 encoded so I don't understand what's happening here.

The problem is, even if I was to change the character to a regular A, there could still be future users with foreign characters in their name, and I'd rather there be something in place to handle this.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

collation `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` works fine for me. 
If you mention your database collation it's define your issue more readable.

Answer (score 0):

In config/database.php :

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

And now make the columns collation as : utf8mb4_unicode_ci.
Hope this works. Thanks.

Comment: The problem is, this is a PostgreSQL which means the utf8mb4 charset and collation do not get recognised. I think I may need to check the data and see if there's another way around it.